# android parse error parsing package

Tags: android, download, installation

I'm developing auto update from inner server.
The download works good, but when I'm trying to install the downloaded apk I'm getting: "parse error, problem parsing package".

```
private BroadcastReceiver mDownloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
            long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
            Log.i(VERSION_LOG_TAG, "received download id: " + downloadId);

            DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
            query.setFilterById(enqueue);
            Cursor cursor = dm.query(query);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);

                if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == cursor.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                    String uriString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                    Log.i(VERSION_LOG_TAG, uriString);

                    Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    File apk = new File(Uri.parse(uriString).getPath());
                    installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apk), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    startActivity(installIntent);
                }else{
                    Log.e(VERSION_LOG_TAG, "download failed");
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I think it's because the url: `content://downloads/my_downloads/13`
**What do I do wrong?**

Comment: The solution for the problem is in the following [question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27404478/android-cant-open-file

Answer (score 0):

Just try to open the downloaded file from file manager application or you can download ex file explorer as it do not access file url directly from within app  then it will not give parse error