# Android can't open file

Tags: android, download, apk, android-download-manager

I'm trying to download an apk file from server via DownloadManager:

```
dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setMimeType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
```

When the apk is downloaded and I press it I'm getting "can't open file message",
But if I download that apk via Browser **instead of DownloadManger**:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

**The apk works fine.**
The device is open for "Unknown sources" and it's version is 4.1.2

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try saving the apk file to your local storage and then opening it using a direct file URI